# Using python, borb and Adobe Acrobat DC the value entered for the last textfield overlays the first three textfields when the file is saved & reopened

Tags: python, pdf, adobe, acrobat, borb

**Environment**

- OS – Windows 10
- Python Version – 3.10.2
- Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (64-bit) |Continuous Release | Version 2021.011.20039 | 64-bit

**Part 1**

1. Using the File Explorer open output_original.pdf using Adobe Acrobat Reader
2. Update the form. For each label enter the corresponding value:

   Name:       Smith

   Surname:    John

   Check No.:  1000

   Amount:     5000
3. Save the file as output_original_results.pdf
4. Exit the reader

**Part 2**

1. Using the File Explorer open output_original_results.pdf using Adobe Acrobat Reader
2. Compare the form values entered vs. the values displayed

   Name:       5000

   Surname:    5000

   Check No.:  5000

   Amount:     5000
3. For each label click on the textfield and verify that the value equals the entered value

**Code**

```
from borb.pdf.document import Document
from borb.pdf.page.page import Page
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.page_layout.multi_column_layout import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.page_layout.page_layout import PageLayout

# Create empty Document
pdf = Document()

# Create empty Page
page = Page()

# Add Page to Document
pdf.append_page(page)

# Create PageLayout
layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

# New import(s)
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.table.fixed_column_width_table import FixedColumnWidthTable
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.forms.text_field import TextField
from borb.pdf.canvas.color.color import HexColor
from decimal import Decimal
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.layout_element import Alignment
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.forms.drop_down_list import DropDownList

# Let's start by adding a heading
layout.add(Paragraph("Patient Information:", font="Helvetica-Bold"))

# Use a table to lay out the form
table: FixedColumnWidthTable = FixedColumnWidthTable(number_of_rows=4, number_of_columns=2)

# Name
table.add(Paragraph("Name : ", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT, font_color=HexColor("56cbf9")))
table.add(TextField(font_color=HexColor("56cbf9"), font_size=Decimal(20)))

# Surname
table.add(Paragraph("Surname : ", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT, font_color=HexColor("56cbf9")))
table.add(TextField(font_color=HexColor("56cbf9"), font_size=Decimal(20)))

table.add(Paragraph("Check No.", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT, font_color=HexColor("56cbf9")))
table.add(TextField(font_color=HexColor("56cbf9"), font_size=Decimal(20)))

table.add(Paragraph("Amount", horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT, font_color=HexColor("56cbf9"))) 
table.add(TextField(font_color=HexColor("56cbf9"), font_size=Decimal(20)))

layout.add(table)

# New import(s)
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF

# Store
with open("output_original.pdf", "wb") as out_file_handle:
    PDF.dumps(out_file_handle, pdf)
enter code here
```

Comment: When you open the generated PDF what are the full field names of all four text boxes? Are they different or are they the same? If the latter, then you've found the problem and need to make sure that all text fields have a different name.

Comment: Indeed, in your code you appear not to name the fields. Thus, they probably all get the same default name and, therefore, present the same value.